# Duplicate that isn't a duplicate

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

My [question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1234471/how-can-i-determine-the-manufacturer-and-model-of-my-monitor) has been flagged as a duplicate when it's clear, at least to me, that it's worlds apart in both scope and relevance to the question that it's meant to be a duplicate of.

Not only is the proposed question specific to laptops, it's also incredibly broad. My question, by contrast, is asking about a piece of hardware specific to desktop computers that it is usually notoriously hard for Windows 7 users to obtain specifics for using a native software solution. This is evidenced by the fact that none of the answers to the proposed question correctly answer mine despite said question having existed since 2009, and by the fact that the only correct answer to my question is a command-line one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### None of the answers to the proposed question correctly answer mine

Please see the instructions in the help article [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://superuser.com/help/duplicates):

> If you see a question and do not agree that it truly is a duplicate, **edit it to highlight the differences**, then try to [get it reopened](https://superuser.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions) by [casting a reopen vote](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: My bad, I missed the option to reopen and assumed that I didn't have the necessary privileges.

Comment: I've now done this.

Comment: Do questions voted to be reopened go into a queue, or is it a matter of waiting for members/mods to discover it organically and then vote?

Comment: @Hashim It goes into the reopen queue. I have reopened it.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Thank you, much appreciated.